# Adding trailing slash to URl gone wrong htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a blog and I'm trying to add trailing slashes to the URLS. THis is working great. However, when I remove the trailing slash at the end, it redirect to the very home directy and the URL looks like:

domain.com/home/fto-username/domains/domain.com/public_html/blog/

Is there a way to still show the content when the user decides -for what reason- to remove the slash at the end of the url?

So: 
domain.com/blog/

shows the same content as:
domain.com/blog

I'm no hero when it comes to URL rewriting. Any help would be appreciated. My htaccess looks as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force www URL
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slash to URL
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php extension in URL
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# Rewrite article.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^article(.*) article.php?blog_post=$1 [NC,L]
```